# Music library deleted from iPhone

Tags: iphone, music, recovery

I switched from the iPhone to a Samsung last May and today decided to charge my old phone to use it as a regular iPod. However, when I turned it on all of my music was gone. The computer I had it back up on crashed last year too so the music on my phone was the only copy. Any ideas on what happened or how I can recover it?

Comment: Did you buy the music from iTunes?

Comment: No. it was all music that I had downloaded onto the phone from my computer. Nothing bought or downloaded from iTunes itself

Comment: The computer wouldn't have a backup copy of the music anyhow since iTunes doesn't back that up. I'll answer, but you likely have a hundreds of dollars recovery expense with poor chances of success.

Comment: What happened to the music though? It was on there when I turned my phone off last may and I turn it on today and its gone.

Comment: Why not try a tool like PhoneView to check if they are really missing?

Comment: Did you sync it after turning it on?

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't back up music files as part of iOS backups since they either came from iTunes Match / iTunes in the Cloud or they came from a computer.

- You should try a tool like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to see if the files are still on the storage and just the catalog has become missing or corrupt.
- You could reconnect it to the computer that has the music.
- You could reconnect it to the cloud music.
- You could pursue data recovery on the device itself - that would likely be extremely expensive or you'd have to be very lucky and have the device jailbroken and no further usage of the storage since each time a new file gets written, it can and will over-write the music.

If the music was truly on the phone, then it would be best to [get a quote from a data-recovery specialist](http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/data-recovery-services/data-recovery-capabilities/) and then see if you want to try DIY recovery and/or if it would be cheaper to get the music elsewhere.